# Camera follow object, rotate EXCEPT z axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I have a camera that is following an aeroplane object, that can rotate left/right. I want to prevent the camera from rotating on this axis (z-axis).

```
this.transform.rotation = Cube.transform.rotation;
```

This obviously rotates the camera in all directions the plane can move in.

I've been trying various things with zAxis etc, only rotating on x and y...

```
this.transform.Rotate(Cube.transform.rotation.xAngle, 0, 0, Space.Self);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

But I can't work it out. Can anyone help?

Comment: something like `Cube.transform.rotation.xAngle` does not exist at all ...

Comment: As soon as you rotate on two (global) axis it can always affect the third (local) axis as well ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way would probably be to just use [`LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) which allows you to rotate the Camera in a way that looks at the target object, without changing it's up direction (=> Z rotation)

I just added a simple smoothing of the position and a position offset - you can of course also scratch what you don't need and set the position directly.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
   // the target to follow
   [SerializeField] private Transform followTarget;
   // local offset to e.g. place the camera behind the target object etc
   [SerializeField] private Vector3 positionOffset;
   // how smooth the camera position is updated, smaller value -> slower
   [SerializeField] private float interpolation = 5f;
   
   private void Update()
   {
      // target position taking the targets rotation and the offset into account
      var targetPosition = followTarget.position + followTarget.forward * positionOffset.z + followTarget.right * positionOffset.x + followTarget.up * positionOffset.y;

      // move smooth towards this target position
      transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, interpolation * Time.deltaTime);
      
      // rotate to look at the target without rotating in Z
      transform.LookAt(followTarget);
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly what I've been looking for! I'm new to Unity, seems like there's quite a few useful things I've yet to discover (like LookAt, here). The only issue is that it's quite jittery. I'll keep playing around with it, but do you know why that might be? Thanks again @derHugo.

Comment: if I just use `Time.deltaTime` as the t parameter for Vector3.Lerp (without multiplying by interpolation), it seems smooth

Comment: Then your interpolation value was probably to large, your object movement itself changes directions too fast .. the factor in the end has to be a value between `0` and `1` and `Time.deltaTime` will be e.g. `0.01666` for 60 FPS

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanna try set the same rotation, and omit the Z axis, as such

```
Vector3 rotation = Cube.transform.rotation;
rotation.z = 0;
this.transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
```

This should set the rotation of the camera to be the same as your cube, without the Z axis.